# Django print data of radio button?

Tags: django

I printed my data within the text box as

```
data = request.GET['information']
print(data)
```

in views.py

```
<form class="homepage" action = "{% url 'count' %}" >
  <textarea name="information" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Wordecounter">
  </form>
```

It is returning the text from the text box but the question is if I used radio button and selected radio button on my browser then how could I print which option I selected in radiobutton from views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do exactly the same, so:

```
data = request.GET['information_radio']
print(data)
```

And your html:

```
<form class="homepage" action = "{% url 'count' %}" >
    <input type="radio" name="information_radio" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="information_radio" value="no">No<br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Wordecounter">
</form>
```